# The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type MyMapOverlay in android? why?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview

i am creating a Geocoder object like.

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
```

here i got this error in eclipse. i.e.

```
The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type MyMapOverlay
```

getBaseContext() is a default method in android.content.ContextWrapper class.

what is the problem here.. any idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: In which class do you create a Geocoder object?
The getBaseContext() does not work in a class which extends from Overlay, because Overlay is not a child of ContextWrapper.
It exists in your MapActivity, if you use one.
The easiest way to solve the issue is to give the Overlay the context as parameter/setter method.

Comment: see this example for Geocoder: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android . they uses the getBaseContext inside the class which extends Overlay. why?

Comment: Because in this example, the MyMapOverlay class is a inner class of the activity and therefor can access everything the MapActivity provide.<br/>
If you create a normal class for your Overlay, you have to hand over the context by yourself.